# Google Chrome using on Ubuntu 15.10 cause random black screen with logout

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome

At work I daily use an HP Compaq Elite 8300 (Intel i7), with Ubuntu Desktop, Eclipse and Netbeans for develop linux embedded software, Java EE application and HTML/Javascript solution, and as browser I use Google Chrome.

Last month I upgrade Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 15.10 by a new clear installation, and then began the problems, the pc randomly crash, show black screen for few seconds, and then logout and redirect me to graphical login screen !

I tried some solution found on web, install last certified Inter Graphics Driver, update Ubuntu, and more other but not solve my problems.

Now I resolve my problem only when I stop to use Google Chrome and switch to Mozilla Firefox.

Probabilly the problem is an incompatibility from Chrome and my current pc's configuration.

Can I do some test to find what's the real problem ?

Thanks.